# adb unable to clear main, system or security logs

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, logcat

I would like to be able to use the Clear Logcat functionality in Android Studio but it fails every single time with "Android logcat error: Failed to clear Logcat, got an exception executing "adb logcat -c". See idea.log for details."

The details in idea.log are:

```
2022-06-26 18:29:32,691 [ 107968]   WARN - ea.logcat.AndroidLogcatService -  
com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:699)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:475)
    at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.executeShellCommand(DeviceImpl.java:706)
    at com.android.tools.idea.logcat.AndroidLogcatService.execute(AndroidLogcatService.java:552)
    at com.android.tools.idea.logcat.AndroidLogcatService.lambda$clearLogcat$2(AndroidLogcatService.java:398)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

To eliminate Android Studio as the culprit, I restarted my PC, rebooted my phone, opened a command window, used adb to obtain a list of the buffers and then tried to clear each of them individually, with mixed results:

```
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb logcat -b all -g
    main: ring buffer is 256Kb (326Kb consumed), max entry is 5120b, max payload is 4068b
    radio: ring buffer is 256Kb (0b consumed), max entry is 5120b, max payload is 4068b
    events: ring buffer is 256Kb (495b consumed), max entry is 5120b, max payload is 4068b
    system: ring buffer is 256Kb (726b consumed), max entry is 5120b, max payload is 4068b
    crash: ring buffer is 256Kb (0b consumed), max entry is 5120b, max payload is 4068b
    kernel: ring buffer is 256Kb (12Kb consumed), max entry is 5120b, max payload is 4068b
    failed to get the readable 'security' log size
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb logcat -b main -c
    failed to clear the 'main' log
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb logcat -b radio -c
    
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb logcat -b events -c

C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb logcat -b system -c
    failed to clear the 'system' log

C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb logcat -b crash -c

C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb logcat -b kernel -c

C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb logcat -b security -c
    failed to clear the 'security' log

C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>
```

I have tried using different version of adb with the same results.

My guess now is that somehow the permissions on the files on the phone are the problem.

My questions are:

1. Is that plausible?
2. Is there something else?
3. Where are the logcat files?
4. What should the permissions be?
5. How do I check the permissions?
6. How do I correct the permissions (if that is necessary)?

Note that the phone is running Android 7.1.2, it is not rooted and, for various reasons, rooting it is not an option.

Comment: Nothing unusual that clearing logcat does not work. I have experienced this occasionally on certain devices. Logact is simply not working correctly on those devices - this is simply a bug of the installed ROM.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I understand it is not unusual--I've come across many reports of problems going back years while investigating. What seems a little different here is that it is not an intermittent problem. It happens every single time, and it never ever works under any circumstances. I'm hoping the rock-solid reproducibility will help in finding the root problem, and a solution.